# Shopware 6 plugin: Constructor gets TraceableEventDispatcher type error

Tags: php, symfony, shopware, shopware6

I have a Shopware 6 plugin with the following `MailHelper` service defined:

```xml
<service id="Swag\\ProductReviews\\Components\\MailHelper" public="true">

    <argument type="service" id="Swag\\ProductReviews\\Service\\ConfigService"/>
        
    <!-- other arguments -->
    
    <argument type="service" id="event_dispatcher" />

</service>
```

In my `MailHelper` constructor, the 11th argument is defined as:

```php
public function __construct(

    // ...

    TraceableEventDispatcher  $eventDispatcher
) {
   // ...
}
```

It works completely fine in the development but in the production, it gives this error:

```rb
@Swag\\ProductReviews\\Components\\MailHelper::__construct(): 
Argument #11 ($eventDispatcher) must be of type 
Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\TraceableEventDispatcher
```

What could be the issue causing this type of error on the event dispatcher argument? How can I resolve it?

Comment: It  is likely due to a difference in the environment between your development and production setups